# Updating a record with primary key as UUID not working in Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate

I am using Spring Boot v1.5.3.RELEASE and MYSQL as Backend for creating Restful service.

I have a `TransactionTbl` table and wanted its primary key to be a uuid type as I think there will be lots of records in that table.

Primary key definition in the Entity:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid",strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
    parameters={ @Parameter (name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
    value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy") })
@GeneratedValue(generator =  "uuid")
@Column(name="txn_id")
private UUID txnId;
```

Code to Update :

```
 txnObj = txnService.findOne(txnObj.getTxnId());
 txnObj.setAmt(someUpdatedAmountValue);
 txnService.save(txnObj);
```

When the above code block runs it throws a  `org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1` error

When I tried switching the primary key from `UUID` to a `Long` with `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` it is working as expected.

Am I defining the UUID in a wrong way or updates like this will not work if we use UUID generation?

Comment: Please log out the SQL statements executed including the values for the bind variables, and let us know what you find.

Comment: @JensSchauder I got the solution. I removed the `parameters` argument from `@GenericGenerator` and added `@Type(type="uuid-char")` annotation which made the mysql primary key as `varchar(255)` ,earlier it was making it `binary(255)`. But I have to still test out what actually removed the problem. was it removing the `parameters` argument or adding the `@Type(type="uuid-char")` or both !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
**@Type(type = "uuid-char")**
@Column(name="txn_id")
private UUID txnId;
```

Normal UUID generation creates the column in database with type Binary. 
Specifying the Type as shown above, while generating the UUID will solve the problem, as it will change the Column type to Varchar
[After adding the Type Annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n37Qm.png)

Comment: Yes I already mentioned in the comments but forgot to add as answer. Anyways as it is the correct answer I will accept it :) .

Comment: It fails with `ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()`