# spring- uuid as primary key cannot be updated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, binary, uuid

I am new to spring

I tried to update an existing value in Mysql using spring rest api and hibernate. but it throws an error everytime.

I have already checked with this below link
[Updating a record with primary key as UUID not working in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843949/updating-a-record-with-primary-key-as-uuid-not-working-in-spring-boot)

But the thing is I dont want to change my my type to varchar.

My RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/users")
public class UserManangementController {

@Autowired
UserManagementService service;

@PutMapping("/put")
public @ResponseBody BaseDTO update(@RequestBody UserManagement management) {
    BaseDTO response = new BaseDTO();
    response = service.update(management);
    return response;
}

}
```

UserManagementService.java

```
@Service
@Log4j2
public class UserManagementService {

@Autowired
UserManagementRepository managementRepository;

public BaseDTO update(UserManagement management) {
BaseDTO response = new BaseDTO();
UserManagement existingMaster = new UserManagement();

try {

    existingMaster = managementRepository.
    findByUserName(management.getUsername());
        if(existingMaster != null) {

            existingMaster.setEmailId(management.getEmailId());
            existingMaster.setName(management.getName());

            managementRepository.save(existingMaster);

            response.setCode(200);
            response.setMessage("Success");
        } else {
            response.setCode(404);
            response.setMessage("Username not found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("<== UserManagementService.update Exception ==>",e);
    }
    return response;
}
}
```

UserManagement.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_management")
@Getter @Setter
public class UserManagement {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "binary(32)")
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "username", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", nullable = false)
private String username;

@Column(name = "email_id", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", nullable = true)
private String emailId;

@Column(name = "phone_number", columnDefinition = "int(10)", nullable = true)
private Long phoneNo;

@Column(name = "password", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)", nullable = false)
private String password;

@JsonIgnore
@Version
private Long version;

}
```

BaseDTO.java

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class BaseDTO implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7420105377584483163L;

private int code = 2000;

private String message;

private List<?> contents;

}
```

UserManagementRepository.java

```
 public interface UserManagementRepository extends JpaRepository<UserManagement, Long> {}
```

Error Message :

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.oasys.entity.UserManagement] with identifier [2582520c-0db8-4577-939e-c12527e960e1]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.oasys.entity.UserManagement#2582520c-0db8-4577-939e-c12527e960e1]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:298) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.save(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com.oasys.service.UserManagementService.update(UserManagementService.java:66) [classes/:?]
at com.oasys.controller.UserManangementController.update(UserManangementController.java:37) [classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:888) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.oasys.entity.UserManagement#2582520c-0db8-4577-939e-c12527e960e1]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3090) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3491) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
... 102 more
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the UUID. You get a StaleObjectStateException that means that the version field has not the same value as you have in the DB. And as I can see you this field is ignored from JSON de/serialization.

Comment: Thanks but the version has not changed. Its still the same.

Comment: Your repository is wrong as well. You have a `UUID` as id-type not a `Long`.

Comment: Have changed the repository and added JSON de/serialization. Still the problem exist.

Comment: do you get the version from the client? Check in the debugger what the value of the version is when you receive it an have a look what it is in the DB.

Comment: Ya checked from client as well as in DB. The version is always 0

Comment: @HarisaravananMohandoss Have you found the solution? I am also stuck on the same problem. I don't want to change the field type to char

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem as my Database accepted the UUID as binary(32). The remaining digits got replaced with zeros. Changed it to binary(16) and got the answer